# UIButton not changing anything with @selector - new Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, selector

Need help. I am trying to change an image of an ImageView using a programmed button. I copied some of the sample codes out here. The sitting on highlighted button works but not doing anything else when clicked. Thanks.

Thanks for the replies. I managed to change the photos but created more problem. I believe it is clear that that I am new to Xcode.

New problems:
1. The new image stays on top so i cannot access the button.
2. I would like to have the image changed only when the button is highlighted.
3. With the new image, it created warning: "Hides instance variable" on the relayImages properties. Thanks again.

```
.h file
 -(void)changeLabel:(UIButton *)sender;
 -(void)addMyButton;
 -(void)addMyImages;
 -(void)addMyLabel;

@property (nonatomic) UIButton *playButton;
@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *relayImages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *checkStatusLabel;
@synthesize relayImages;


.m file
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self addMyImages];
[self addMyButton];
[self addMyLabel];



// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)addMyButton
{
UIButton *playButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 348, 20, 78)];
UIImage *offState = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PBNoOff.png"];
[playButton setBackgroundImage:offState forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *onState = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PBNoOn.png"];
[playButton setBackgroundImage:onState forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeLabel:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:playButton];

}

-(void)changeLabel:(UIButton *)sender
{


UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1_2RelaysOn.png"];
UIImageView *relayImages = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
relayImages.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
relayImages.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:relayImages];
[self.view addSubview:_playButton];


 }


-(void)addMyImages
{
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1_2RelaysOff.png"];
UIImageView *relayImages = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
relayImages.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
relayImages.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:relayImages];

}

-(void)addMyLabel
{
UILabel *checkStatusLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 200, 30)];
checkStatusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
checkStatusLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:checkStatusLabel];

}
```

Comment: where do you create relayImages?

Comment: put breakpoint wheather it is called or not..

Comment: is any of the changeLabel code impacting on the view?

Comment: The code you've posted looks fine. The problem is likely in the code you didn't share.

Comment: the series:-(void)addMyButton, -(void)changeLabel:(UIButton *)sender, -(void)addMyImages, -(void)addMyLabel. Does sequence make a  big  difference? Thanks

Comment: you are not initilize your relayImages view...code working fine

Comment: I am assuming relayImages is your imageView object, correct? Have you verified that this is correctly hooked up as an outlet? You could also just add a quick NSLog in changeLabel and verify whether that method is actually being messaged when you click on your button.

Comment: Nicola, I am just checking if the label will change as the image is not changing. Sort of double check if it is the label or the method that is not working.

Comment: actually what you are trying to do?set the button images when its control state highlighted only.you are using same name for image view like realyImages both global and local so its shows the warning hides instance variable change some other name.

Comment: What I did was the button changes when highlighted and same goes with the image of a UIImageView. My problem earlier was that I wanted to connect to the highlighted event and eventually other button events which you nailed. Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this i am created custom imageView

.m file

```
  -(void)addMyButton
{
    _playButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 348, 60, 50)];
    [_playButton setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_playButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    UIImage *offState = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
//    [playButton setBackgroundImage:offState forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//    UIImage *onState = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PBNoOn.png"];
    [_playButton setBackgroundImage:offState forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeLabel:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:_playButton];

}

-(void)changeLabel:(UIButton *)sender
{


    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"];
    relayImages = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
    relayImages.frame = CGRectMake(20, 100, 100, 100);
    relayImages.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:relayImages];


}


-(void)addMyImages
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"];
    UIImageView *someImages = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    someImages.frame = CGRectMake(20, 200, 100, 100);
    someImages.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:someImages];

}



  -(void)addMyLabel
{
 _checkStatusLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 250, 100, 30)];
    _checkStatusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    _checkStatusLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_checkStatusLabel];

}
```

.h file

```
-(void)changeLabel:(UIButton *)sender;
-(void)addMyButton;
-(void)addMyImages;
-(void)addMyLabel;
@property (nonatomic) UIButton *playButton;
@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *relayImages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *checkStatusLabel;
```

and viewdidload

```
 [self addMyButton];
    [self addMyImages];
    [self addMyLabel];
```

Comment: Tried it, added the cgrect and worked. This solved some of the problems including image on top of the pile when I managed to change it. Hope you can also solve the other issues. Thank you very much karthikeyan.